# Method signatures in classes which extend a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, method-signature

If I have a generic class like this:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
  public string Greeting(T t)
  {
    return "Hi, I'm " + t.ToString();
  }
}
```

which is extended like this:

```
public class FooRepository : Repository<Foo>
```

If FooRepository has a method called `Greeting(Foo foo)`, does that method have the same signature as the base class method (i.e. hide or override it), or is it considered separate?

I'm a little confused to be honest.

Comment: Have you tested it? Did it compile? Were there errors?

Comment: I was confused about what Visual Studio was doing, so I wanted to establish what the theory was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hides the base method and the compiler will warn you about this. If you want to override it you need to mark it as `virtual` in the base class or use the `new` keyword in the derived class method to indicate to the compiler that you know what you are doing and the hiding is intentional.